# How to use clipboard in WinRT - C++/WinRT coroutine assertion !is_sta()

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++20, c++-winrt

I want to set bitmap image to the clipboard.
But failed to set clipboard using coroutine.
Please tell me the correct way to create bitmap object and set clipboard its.

My facing problems are following.

- `!is_sta()` caught assertion. Of cause, I understand to use STA model, but I don't know avoiding method.
- Clipboard feature is not working when the ignoring above error. (The error name is `WinRT originate error` but I seem the message that isn't truth answer.)

And I'm not familiar with C++ coroutine and WinRT thread model.
So my opinion maybe wrong too.

The following code is working in main function (can paste bitmap image to Power Point 2013) but the `not_working` function is not working due to some problems.
What's difference in each methods?

Regards.

```
#include <winrt/base.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <winrt/Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Graphics.Imaging.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.Streams.h>
#include <random>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace winrt::Windows::Graphics::Imaging;
using namespace winrt::Windows::ApplicationModel::DataTransfer;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Storage::Streams;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation;

#pragma comment(lib, "WindowsApp")

IAsyncAction not_working()
{
  std::random_device seed_gen;
  std::mt19937 engine(seed_gen());

  std::vector<uint8_t> data(100 * 100 * 4);
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < std::size(data); ++i)
  {
    data[i] = static_cast<std::uint8_t>(engine() * 255);
  }

  auto stream = InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
  auto encoder = co_await BitmapEncoder::CreateAsync(
    BitmapEncoder::BmpEncoderId(), stream
  ); // Assertion !is_sta()
  encoder.SetPixelData(
    BitmapPixelFormat::Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode::Straight,
    100, 100, 1.0, 1.0, data
  );
  co_await encoder.FlushAsync();

  auto package = DataPackage();
  package.SetBitmap(RandomAccessStreamReference::CreateFromStream(stream));

  Clipboard::Clipboard::Clear();
  Clipboard::SetContent(package);
  Clipboard::Flush(); // WinRT originate error 

}

int main() 
{
  SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
  //winrt::init_apartment(winrt::apartment_type::multi_threaded);
  winrt::init_apartment(winrt::apartment_type::single_threaded);

  try
  {
    std::random_device seed_gen;
    std::mt19937 engine(seed_gen());

    std::vector<uint8_t> data(100 * 100 * 4);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < std::size(data); ++i)
    {
      data[i] = static_cast<std::uint8_t>(engine() * 255);
    }

    auto stream = InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    auto encoder = BitmapEncoder::CreateAsync(
      BitmapEncoder::BmpEncoderId(), stream
    ).get();
    encoder.SetPixelData(
      BitmapPixelFormat::Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode::Straight,
      100, 100, 1.0, 1.0, data
    );
    encoder.FlushAsync().get();

    auto package = DataPackage();
    package.SetBitmap(RandomAccessStreamReference::CreateFromStream(stream));

    Clipboard::Clipboard::Clear();
    Clipboard::SetContent(package);
    Clipboard::Flush();
  }
  catch (winrt::hresult_error const& ex)
  {
    winrt::hresult hr = ex.to_abi(); // HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).
    winrt::hstring message = ex.message(); // The system cannot find the file specified.
    std::cout << (int)hr << std::endl;
    std::cout << winrt::to_string(message) << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you try to remove Flush where after `SetContent` method?

Comment: I tried your advise. The method works right. But why does `Flush` method raise an exception? I understand `Flush`  method use to keep clipboard data after quiting application. But I can paste data after quiting application without flush method.

Answer (score 2):

The [Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard?view=winrt-18362) apis can only be accessed when the calling application is in focus on the UI thread, we need to call it from the UI thread. You can co_await the winrt::resume_foreground function to switch to a specific foreground thread. Now we can use the DispatcherQueue to work with winrt::resume_foreground function. For example:

```
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Core.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.System.h>

using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Core;
using namespace winrt::Windows::System;

IAsyncAction not_working(DispatcherQueue queue)
{
    std::random_device seed_gen;
    std::mt19937 engine(seed_gen());

    std::vector<uint8_t> data(100 * 100 * 4);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < std::size(data); ++i)
    {
        data[i] = static_cast<std::uint8_t>(engine() * 255);
    }

    auto stream = InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

    auto encoder = co_await BitmapEncoder::CreateAsync(
        BitmapEncoder::BmpEncoderId(), stream
    ); // Assertion !is_sta()
    encoder.SetPixelData(
        BitmapPixelFormat::Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode::Straight,
        100, 100, 1.0, 1.0, data
    );
    co_await encoder.FlushAsync();

    auto package = DataPackage();
    package.SetBitmap(RandomAccessStreamReference::CreateFromStream(stream));

    //add resume_foreground
    co_await winrt::resume_foreground(queue);

    Clipboard::Clipboard::Clear();
    Clipboard::SetContent(package);
    Clipboard::Flush(); // WinRT originate error 
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);

    winrt::init_apartment();

    auto controller{ DispatcherQueueController::CreateOnDedicatedThread() };
    not_working(controller.DispatcherQueue()).get();

    return 0;
}
```

For more details about this, you can refer to: [More advanced concurrency and asynchrony with C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency-2).

Comment: On the line `co_await winrt::resume_foreground(queue);` has compile error. I seem more include file on my environment (Build 1809, VS  2019 version 16.5.4). Do you have any idea?

Comment: Have you included the Windows.System.h header file? If you have included, what is the error information?

Comment: Yes, I have included. The compile error is C2440 (Failed to cast DspatcherQueue to CoreDispatcher).

Comment: If you set the target and min version to 10.0.18362.0, will the same issue occur?